# Inherited 'Get' function will not return correct value

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance

I have a base class BankAccount, then 3 derived classes: SavingsAccount, CheckingAccount, and AchieverAccount(also inheriting checking). The only get_ function is in the base class public. When I call it from the 3 derived classes it returns 0, which I assume is that base class's constructor's doing. I made the getBalance function with this->balance(); as a test to see if it would return the balance, no luck, I had it as just return balance; before hand. I have tried to make the balance public, even though it isn't a good idea and still nothing. So it has to be that the SavingsAccount isn't inheriting it right, or getBalance isn't getting the right balance, in which can I need help.

I'm not going to include all of the code because it turns out to be a lot, but I'll put it what I think is important, if you want I can put it all in though. This is only for SavingsAccount, because I think if I get help on this I can figure it out elsewhere.

All of these have #include  and using namespace std;

---

BankAccount.h

---

```
class BankAccount{
public: 
    BankAccount();
    BankAccount(double amount);
    double getBalance();
};
private:
    double balance;
```

---

BankAccount.cpp

---

```
#include "BankAccount.h"
BankAccount::BankAccount(){
    balance = 0;
}

BankAccount::BankAccount(double amount){
    balance = amount;
}

double BankAccount::getBalance(){
    return this->balance;
}
```

---

SavingsAccount.h

---

```
#include "BankAccount.h"
class SavingsAccount: virtual public BankAccount{
public:
    SavingsAccount();
    SavingsAccount(double amount);

private:   
    double balance;
};
```

---

SavingsAccount.cpp

---

```
#include "SavingsAccount.h"
SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(){
    balance = 0.00;
}

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(double amount){  
    balance = amount;
    interest = .09;
}
```

---

Main.cpp

---

```
#include "SavingsAccount.h"
#include "BankAccount.h"
void main(){
    cout << "Creating new SavingsAccount with $2000.00" << endl;
    SavingsAccount sa(2000.00);

cout << "Current balance: $" << sa.getBalance() << endl;
}
```

---

Output

---

Creating new SavingsAccount with $2000.00
Current balance: $0.00

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Presumably that's not all of your code because you use `balance` as a member variable in `BankAccount` but it isn't in the class definition you've shown.  Why are you inheriting virtually from `BankAccount` and why do you have another `balance` member in `SavingsAccount`?

Comment: I believe I figured it out. I made the base class member protected, and removed the SavingsAccount initialization of balance, it seems to work.

Comment: Never mind that did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BankAccount` class very likely has a member named `balance` (not shown in your code for some reason) - otherwise `BankAccount(double)` constructor wouldn't compile.

`SavingsAccount` class also has a member named `balance`. Realize that `SavingsAccount::balance` is distinct from and unrelated to `BankAccount::balance`. `SavingsAccount`'s constructor initializes the former, while `BankAccount::getBalance` returns the value of the latter.

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
class BankAccount {
  double balance;
public:
  BankAccount(double value) : balance(value) {}
  double getBalance() const { return balance; }
};

class SavingsAccount : public BankAccount {
public:
  SavingsAccount(double value) : BankAccount(value) {}
};
```

I suggest you read about constructor initializer lists in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: Sounds right. So where do I go from there? Do I have to send the balance of SavingsAccount through reference? or is there a simpler way?

Comment: That rather depends on what you are trying to achieve, which you've never explained. Having said that, I've added a simple example to my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: I knew I hadn't learned something fundamental to this. Thanks, that pretty much cleared it up I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a balance variable declared for the base class yet you refer to it.. how is this working? I assume you have one and just did not copy it in here..

However the issue is your savings account declares a balance as well which would get set to 2000. but your getBalance defined in your parent class cannot see that value and return 0.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to have a single savings variable for each account? In that case, you should not redefine savings in the derived class. You are calling the get in the base class and getting 0 returned.